# Creatung and running Abaqus geometry in Spyder, not opening Abaqus command

Tags: python, command-line, scripting, abaqus

I am trying to run my script with a creation of an abaqus geometry. I know that the command in Abaqus Command is abaqus cae noGui=create_part.py. However, how can I do this in a python compiler such as Spyder?

I've written a script for accessing python inside Spyder:

```
import create_part
abaqusPath = "C:\\SIMULIA\\Commands\\abaqus.cmd /C"
args = abaqusPath + "abaqus python test.py"
create_part.call(args)
```

However, when running it, I get the message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'part'

This is due to the command: from part import *

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Abaqus python module is proprietary and you need Abaqus to access it, meaning you can't run it outside of the Abaqus command.